# How to secure an API connection from a static site hosted on a CDN

Tags: api, security, serverless, static-site

How can I protect an API request sent from a static site hosted on a CDN?

Use case:
A single page application using react is hosted on S3 + Cloudfront. The site calls the Yahoo Finance API to request some market data. The third-party API uses an API key to authenticate the requests. I can only store the third party API key in the static site making it available for anyone.

Considerations:

- The static site and the API are not in the same cloud provider or service, so a solution using roles wouldn't work.
- A Lambda (Function) proxy solution is my best choice at the moment IMO but this would still allow a request to be sent directly to the Lambda (Function).
- The request to the function should also be secure, making the above option still vulnerable. This means that getting the URL to the Proxy Function from the source code and calling the Function is not acceptable either.

Looked around at some other questions posted but I haven't found one that addresses the particular circumstances stated here.

Comment: Long story short: there is no way you can have that secured without some kind of proxy that also ensures user authentication and checks his access rights.